# Jquery add remove function

Tags: jquery

Hi i am new in jquery and i am adding a form on click function to my form everything is working fine. **But i don't want to show remove button with form first i only want to display my added form remove button after i click**

Here is my code

```
$('#addFiles').click(function() {
    img_input = '<input name="image[#count#]"  type="file">';
    img_input = img_input.replace(new RegExp('#count#', 'g'),count);

    htmlstr =
    '<div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">\
    <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">\
      <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=no+image" alt="" />\
    </div>\
    <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 20px;"></div>\
    <div>\
      <span class="btn btn-white btn-file">\
        <span class="btn btn-file fileinput-button">\
          <span>Upload Image </span>\
          '+img_input+'\
        </span>\
      </span>\
      \<a id="removeField" class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="remove_row(this)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>\
    </div>\
  </div>\
</div>';
$('#form-image').append(htmlstr);
count++;
i++;
return false;
});

  $('#addFiles').click();

});

function remove_row(obj){
  $(obj).parent().parent().remove();
}
```

Comment: Do not use that form of multi-line string. One misplaced space and you are hosed.

Comment: can you show your problem in snippet or fiddle??

Comment: I'm assuming the remove button should only show when that form is submitted. Is that correct? I don't see any variables that holds that info. It looks like you are jumping directly into writing the UI without considering how the users information is handled. You should probably add a central state object that can be used to draw the ui in any state. It looks like you are drawing within a callback instead of modifying the data. You should only draw to the UI when the data save is confirmed. The data is supposed to control the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can hide remove button for the first item, do something like this.

```
// html change
<a id="removeField" class="btn btn-danger remove-btn" type="button" onclick="remove_row(this)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>

// jquery change, call this statemet after every append.
$('#form-image').find('.fileupload').first().find('.remove-btn').hide()
```